# Using MATLAB sendmail off cron

Tags: linux, matlab, cron, sendmail

I am using Matlab R2014b on Red Hat Linux and have a function that creates image files and then uses the sendmail command to email them to a small list of accounts. I can use the function just fine from the Matlab Command Window, sending emails and all. But from the CLI, it creates all the files but chokes when sending. It gives a connection timeout error after it cannot connect to my smtp server. My eventual goal is to run this from a crontab. Why would specifically the sendmail command work from the Command Window, but not from the command line?

My CLI command looks like this:

```
matlab -nosplash -r "run('/full/path/to/script.m')"
```

and the sendmail command is not much more that this:

```
sendmail({'u1@email.com', 'u2@email.com'}, 'Subject', 'Message', {'attach1.jpg', 'attach2.jpg'})
```

Thanks! I appreciate any help I can get.

-Brett